# Batch syntaxerror on "for"-statement

Tags: string, batch-file, syntax-error

I am trying to automate a little deploymentscript using batch. It only updates a SVN-repo then uses ant to build and upload. After that it connects to the server via SSH using plink to restart the Server.
That all works fine. Now the problem is, when I try to parse the Serverstats, to see if the relevant Servers are back up, I get a Syntaxerror.
Here is the relevant codesnippet:

```
SET c=0
SET problem=false
echo outer
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('plink.exe -v -ssh %uID%@%serveradress% -pw %pw% %command%') do (
    echo inner
    if %c% GEQ 3 (
        if %c% LEQ 8 (
            echo(%%i|findstr /r /c:"up" >nul && (
            ) || (
                set problem=true
            )
        )
    ) 
    set c+=1
)
echo %problem%
```

And here is the output of this snippet:

```
...>SET c=0
...>SET problem=false
...>echo outer
outer
")" not processable syntactically (translated from german. It probably says something else in english)
...> )||(
```

Comment: Can you give some examples to the values in the variables?  (uID, serveraddress, pw, command, and string)  Just at a glance my guess would be a special character in one of those variables is causing the trouble.  However, you will also need to implement DelayedExpansion for the `!c!` variable and add the arithmetic flag to the set command `set /a c+=1`

Comment: The only special character that can occur is # in the username. Would that be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a syntax error because your `&&( )` has no command. You could use `&&(rem)`, or you could remove `&&` altogether and go straight to `||(...)`.

But you still have problems. Expansion of `%c%` occurrs when the line is parsed, and your entire FOR DO () loop is parsed in one pass. So the value of `%c%` does not change with each iteration - it remains the constant value of 0 that was set before you entered your loop.

You can solve that problem by enabling delayed expansion at the top using

`setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`, and use `!c!` instead of `%c%`.

You can avoid delayed expansion by intentionally using division by zero error to see if `c` is within the range of 3-8.

The following:

```
2>nul set /a "1/((c/3)*!(c/9))" && (
  rem do something
)
```

is equivalent to:

```
if !c! geq 3 if !c! leq 8 (
  rem do something
)
```